# How to a terminate a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that defines a word and I am making guesses of letters that form the actual word. It works perfectly, but I am unable to terminate the loop from taking in user input after I obtain the correct formation of letters. Does any one have an idea in terminating the loop?

```
word = "EVAPORATE"
guessed_word = "_" * len(word)
word = list(word)
guessed_word = list(guessed_word)
new_list = []
while True:
    guess_letter = input("Enter a guess: ")
    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter == guess_letter:
            guessed_word[index] = letter
    print(' '.join(guessed_word))
```

Comment: may be `while word != guessed_word`?

Comment: @adamkwm Yup, that's it! Could you post that as an answer please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
word = "EVAPORATE"
word  = word.lower()
word = list(word)
guessed_word = "_" * len(word)
guessed_word = list(guessed_word)
new_list = []
while True:
    guess_letter = input("Enter a guess: ")
    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter == guess_letter:
            guessed_word[index] = letter
    print(' '.join(guessed_word))

    if '_' not in guessed_word:
        print('Congratulation!')
        break
```

Comment: A quick question, do you know how to incorporate an if statement if a letter already exists in guess_word  and thus indicating that to the user and also asking the user to try again. I've tried implementing that, but it has some wild output. Thanks

Comment: perhaps, just after the user input, check if a letter is already in the guess_word. If it is give a message and then use 'continue' which will skip the remainder of the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change `while True` to `while word != guessed_word`, then it will stop after you obtain the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should get to know about flow control statements being [break](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue), continue and pass. Look at break for this particular question

Answer (score -1):

You can use `break`.
For example...

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    n -= 1
    if n == 2:
        break
    print(n)
print('Loop ended.')
```

Comment: Why not use `while n != 2` or `while n > 2`?